# Is a cyclic redundancy check required in a BLE service

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, adafruit, nrf51

In this app by Nordic

https://github.com/adafruit/Bluefruit_LE_Connect_Android

a cyclic redundancy check (CRC) is added to the payload byte array before writing it to the UART receiving characteristic.

Is the CRC necessary? Doesn't the BLE stack add its own preamble, CRC, etc. to filter out noise?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

No it shouldn't be necessary. Each packet already has a 24-bit CRC when transferred over the air.